# jQuery TimeAgo library to change color of Text if the DateTime is in the Past?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

I am using the **[Yarp jQuery TimeAgo library](http://timeago.yarp.com/)** in my new App in which I am showing relative timing for a Task records **Due Date** field.

What I want to do is simply show the date/time value as **RED Text** once the set **Due Date** value is in the past tense based on the current date.

So real simple, Future Due Date will show default green text set with CSS on the page:
[image]

Past Due Date will show Red text:

[image]

The library can be found here:  http://timeago.yarp.com/

Can anyone help me to color past due text in Red?

The HTML on the page before the library converts it into a future or past DateTime in words looks like this...

```
<time id="duedatetimeago"></time>
```

After the library does it's magic on the element, it simply looks like this...

```
<time id="duedatetimeago">16 days ago</time>
```

So you can see no special CSS classes or data attributes or anything are added so it might be difficult to know when the current time is in the past.  If you find out "anybody" then please share with me, thank you

Comment: I need this as well, any ideas anyone?

Comment: This is being tracked as a feature request for the project at GitHub : https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/issues/223

Comment: I was able to achieve this by doing my date comparison outside of the timeAgo plugin.  I assign my CSS class based on the date being future or past.  It would be really nice if this was built into the timeago library though and I think many people would find it useful if anyone is able to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/jakerb/8b329401a2ea51f80b9a) containing modifications to timeago.js - you can change the default past and future colors within the `inPastColor` variable on line `49`